# ruby on rails how to download csv file using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, reactjs

Some clarifications first.

I'm trying everything on local development environment.

In my `UsersController` I have a `summary_csv` method that builds a csv file and stores it in the `/tmp/your-csv-file.csv` location .

Once the system checks that the file is ready for download, I have a `summary_csv.js.erb` file that runs some javascript to help the user download the file, specifically, in `summary_csv.js.erb`, I try to do   `window.location="/users/download_csv";` and there is a `download_csv` method in the `Users` controller.

So I want the download to happen, but not sure about 2 things:

1. How should I configure `routes.rb` for this `download_csv` method
   so that the download happens without throwing some kind of 'missing
   views' error? (at this point I don't care whether user has to
   directed to another view or can stay on the same page).
2. What should go into the body of `download_csv` method so that 
   `window.location="/users/download_csv";` will initiate the download,
   for the file located at `/tmp/your-csv-file.csv`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding out the solution. Thanks to all who offered help

So `window.location` was the best method to use after all.
1) Set it to `controller/method` . 
2) `send_file` appropriately in the body of the above method . 
3) Set the correct routes in the right order.

Step 3 was critical to getting it work.
The route for `controller/method` must be configured exactly to not make Rails confused as to where it should route your action.

```
resources :users do
  collection do
    get 'download_csv' => 'specify which controller#which_method_name'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Put a get method inside users resource and collections like this

```
resources :users do
  collection do
    get 'download_csv'
  end
end
```

2) You just need to send_file, passing your file path to it, since it's ready.

Result

```
def download_csv
  send_file(
    "/tmp/your-csv-file.csv",
    filename: "your_custom_file_name.csv",
    type: "text/csv"
  )
end
```

Comment: i tried this and nothing happens... `development.log` says   "Sent File <file>" but nothing happens... i was doing this on local development server.. maybe that's why?

Comment: and for some reasons it's triggering my Users `show` method and saying undefined id=download_csv...

Comment: @namesake22 your show method is being called because you probably didn't declare any route, I tried to tell you to declare it the way you do for every other, not to not declare hehe. I will edit my answer

Comment: i'll try this next Monday but can you please explain what's happenig with `winow.location=`?

Comment: @namesake22 is just a way javascript have to navigate through urls without ajax. `The window.location object can be used to get the current page address (URL) and to redirect the browser to a new page`. I don't like it hehe. You could call your download directly without that window.location if you wanted

Comment: what would be the better way without the `window.location` method? I tried just calling the controller action `download_csv` and have it do `send_file` but nothing happens...

Comment: @namesake22 I would need to see a lot more of your code, to propose another way

Comment: i can do that but in the meanwhile is it true that `send_file` within controller action will not respond to ajax request? that was why I used `window.location` in the first place

Comment: No, that's not true. But when doing Ajax call for getting file you have to code a receive function in JavaScript as well, within your client side